# Intermittent error on ASP.NET app. Related to IIS and DefaultAppPool

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a very bizarre intermittent problem that occurs with some **ASP.NET 4 (C#)** application code .

The error on **Event Viewer System** is:

```
Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   W3SVC
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1011
Date:       25/08/2014
Time:       14.28.19
User:       N/A
Computer:   12345678
Description:
A process serving application pool 'DefaultAppPool' suffered a fatal 
communication error with the World Wide Web Publishing Service. The 
process id was '1860'.
```

I have read this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885654 and I have monitored the **w3wp.exe** process on **Process Monitor** http://technet.microsoft.com/it-it/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx.

The bizarre intermittent problem that occurs when this sequence is activated.

How to do solve this ?

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Time of Day,"Process Name","PID","Operation","Path","Result","Detail","User"
14.28.19,2485741,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 256","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,2486492,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,2487233,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 64","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,2487464,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 2","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,2487878,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,2489484,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,2489621,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 64","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,2490272,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4553146,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\index80.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 256","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4553883,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\index80.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4554632,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\index80.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 64","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4554769,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\index80.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 2","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4555180,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\index80.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4556781,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\index80.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4556915,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\index80.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 64","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4557560,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\index80.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4570685,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 256","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4571366,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4571942,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 64","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4572076,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 2","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4572417,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4573738,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4573872,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 64","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4574436,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4591039,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 256","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4591715,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4592282,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 64","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4592416,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 2","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4592749,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4594084,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4594215,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 64","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4594763,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4668543,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 256","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4669286,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4670954,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 64","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4671102,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 2","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4671502,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4673024,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4673158,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 64","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
14.28.19,4673770,"w3wp.exe","1860","ReadFile","C:\WINDOWS\assembly\pubpol1.dat","END OF FILE","Offset: 0, Length: 512","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE"
```